# Printing Bootstrap Form Selections Using Printjs

Tags: printjs

I'm using http://printjs.crabbly.com/ to print a defined area on an HTML page (a form) using the HTML output functionality of the library.

I'm having trouble getting printjs to print out selections from dropdowns in a form. When you print HTML with  divs, the content of the  divs print on the page, but dropdowns in the form, where users can select an option from a limited list, print only the top option in the HTML, rather than the selected option (Bootstrap Example):

```
<select class="form-control">
<option>E</option>
<option>G</option>
<option>S</option>
<option>N</option>
```

Is there something I can do to get the printed output to include the selections from the dropdown lists?

[Image of dropdown selections not rendering in printout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj6FY.gif)

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.